# PHP date_sub. can't substract today and date

Tags: php, date, datediff

I am trying to output number of days between today and the date I enter so I have a problem I encounter error: "Warning: date_diff() expects parameter 2 to be DateTimeInterface" So what's the problem ?

```html
<?php

$today=date("y-m-d");
$date=date_create("2016-09-16");

echo date_diff($date,$today);

?>
```

Comment: rtfm: http://php.net/date  it returns a **STRING**, not a datetime object.

Comment: @MarcB so does that mean i have to insert $today into strtotime() function ?

Comment: rtfm: http://php.net/strtotime it returns an INTEGER, not a datetime object. You really should just read the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies in that when using `date_diff` you have to make sure that you're comparing objects that are actual date objects.  Also the return type for `date_diff` is a DateInterval object. You're treating it as a string.

```
$today = new DateTime(); // $today is a DateTime object
$date = new DateTime("2016-09-16"); // $date is also a DateTime object!
$diff =  date_diff($date,$today); // compare two objects of the same type FTW!

echo $diff->days; // $diff is a DateInterval object, so echo it's 'days' property.

// output: 3 (as of this writing)
```

**Further reading:**
http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php
http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php